# How can I change background color of each list item in Css?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I want to change the background-color first,fifth,seventh list item yellow and second,fourth,eighth list item green and third,sixth list item purple, How can I do it?

```
li:nth-child(2n+1){
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the specificity and cascading rules of CSS to your advantage here:

1. Make every element background `yellow`.
2. Then target every **even** element - which will get you your second, fourth sixth, and eighth.
3. Now, we can use the 3n+3 to target the third and override the sixth element from the **even** rule.

```css
li {
  background-color: yellow;
}

li:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: green;
}

li:nth-child(3n+3) {
  background-color: purple;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>one</li>
  <li>two</li>
  <li>three</li>
  <li>four</li>
  <li>five</li>
  <li>six</li>
  <li>seven</li>
  <li>eight</li>
</ul>
```